# Antivirus Software blocking VB.NET Application

Tags: vb.net, deployment, installation, antivirus

I have designed an application in VB.NET.

When its installer is run on the user's workstation, the antivirus software blocks the application.

Does anyone know how I can register my software application so that it will not be blocked by any antivirus software.?

Comment: This is gonna be different for every antivirus out there. You will not be able to do this for other people's computers though.

Comment: You can't. There is no central "do not block" list across all antivirus vendors. A better question to ask is: what is your application doing such that the antivirus feels compelled to block it?

Comment: Anti-virus software does not work by registering applications. It works by looking at behavior heuristics... patterns that look like things a virus might do. If you don't want your app to be blocked by antivirus software, stop doing virus-like things.

Comment: I think it's a job for your users! and should be done manually!

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn: how would i know the reason why the app is being blocked?

Answer (score 2):

You should look at the reason that the antivirus programs are blocking your program, for example is it based on reputation?  Is your program signed? etc.

Comment: How can i know that? How will i come to know the reason behind why the app is being blocked?

Comment: submit your setup file/executable here: https://www.hybrid-analysis.com/  (it takes a while to come back with the detailed analysis)